# Symfony2 500 response on shared hosting

Tags: symfony, shared-hosting

I have a working Symfony2 application running on my local server that I want to upload to my shared hosting. When I try to open the website on my shared hosting I get a 500 response.

I perform these steps:

1. Clear the cache ("php app/console cache:clear" and "php app/console cache:clear --env=prod")
2. Upload /app, /src, /vendor, /web to shared hosting
3. Make /logs and /cache writable (and all subfolders/files)

When I open "www.mydomain.com/app.php" I'm getting a 500 response. When I open "www.mydomain.com/app_dev.php" Symfony gives (the expected and correct) message that I'm not allowed to open this file.

The /logs/prod.log is empty.

It's not possible for me to clear the cache on the shared hosting server because I don't have SHH access. I can only clear the cache on my local server and then upload the files.

I didn't change my /web/.htaccess file, this is in it:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Try to remove the lines preventing you to access config.php from outside to see if your configuration is ok. DO NOT FORGET to remove/restore the file once you are done.

Comment: I'm getting the Welcome page. Only some "Recommendations" are given: install intl, install accelerator, Set short_open_tag to off.

Comment: And if you do the same with app_dev.php and call it?

Comment: I get the 500 response, but this time with the message: file_get_contents(F:\wamp\www\MySite\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle/Resources/views/Profiler/toolbar_js.html.twig): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in mydomain.com/mm/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php line 126. So it tries to load the file from my F: drive, which of course fails.

Comment: What if you clear you app/cache folder manually (rm -rf app/cache/*) and try again?

Comment: Thx, that seems to work. But why didn't I get a message in log/prod.log?

Comment: Not sure...do you have anything in it right now?

Comment: Strange... there are debug messages in dev.log, but prod.log is empty. If you submit your answer below I can accept is. This log thing might be a separate issue.

Comment: If the application fails to boot, it's likely that the logger service won't exist and wont be able to log anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seemed to be the command `php app/console cache:clear" and "php app/console cache:clear --env=prod` didn't completely clear the cache folder.

It can happen if the user running the command hasn't the permission to delete files/folder in app/cache/
Manually removing the content of this folder can solve the issue (`rm -rf app/cache/*`).

Comment: Interestingly, this fixed the same issue for me also, thanks. The command example you give, however, is a little worrying for copy-pasters like me (rm -rf /app/cache/* should be rm -rf app/cache/*)

Comment: @JakeWorrell It was a typo. Thanks for the comment!